# Z80 16-Bit Load Instruction and Endianness

Tags: assembly, emulation, endianness, instruction-set, z80

I'm writing a ZX Spectrum emulator in C# "for fun" (I think I regret starting already).

I know the Z80 is little endian, so in RAM the low-order byte is stored first.

What I can't seem to find a definitive answer to, is how it behaves with a 16-bit `LD` instruction.

For example:

```
LD BC, 0x1234
```

After this, does `B` contain `0x12` and `C` contain `0x34` or vice-versa?

So, after the above, if I execute:

```
LD A, 0x56
LD (BC), A
```

Will memory `0x1234` or `0x3412` contain `0x56`?

It would be nice if someone could provide a link to a reliable source.

Comment: There is other register pair.. HL... It works in the same manner... Guess what H and L stands for...

Comment: You wrote the instruction the way a disassembler displays it or you write it in assembly.  It uses the "natural" order, humans like their most significant byte on the left and the least significant on the right.  Same story for register pairs, BC has the most significant register on the left.  Your emulator however sees 0x01 0x34 0x12.  Little-endian, 0x34 is first.  Only the memory bus interface has the endian detail.

Comment: Values in asm source are *values*, not encodings; they use normal most-significant-digit first order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Endian-ness only comes into play when we break a 16-bit value into two 8-bit pieces, *and there is a choice of approaches, which happens when such a 16-bit value is stored in memory* so, for example:

- With the *encoding* of immediates in instructions, such as `ld bc, 0x1234`: looking at the individual bytes of the machine code for this instruction, we will see 0x01 0x34 0x12, storing the 0x1234 in little endian byte order.
- With a 16-bit value as data in memory, and looking at the individual bytes in memory, needs an endian-ness, so use little endian.

However, if the `BC` register pair is loaded with a value 0x1234, then that's the memory address that indirect use of `BC` will work with.  There's no issue of endian-ness with this, since we're not looking at the individual bytes in this scenario.

Now, if you want to know how the `BC` register composes from `B` and `C` then we have to know which is the high order and which is the low order.

From the manual:

> PUSH BC is PUSH B then C

So, that means that the stack memory will have the value from `C` then the value from `B` at the address +1 higher than where `C` was stored.  Since 16-bit data in memory is stored using little endian byte order, we can conclude that C is the low order and B is the high order of the `BC` 16-bit register pair.

Thus, `BC` is `B` * 256 + `C`.  Let's note though, that this is simply by definition, but doesn't really go to endian-ness — since there's no "addressing" of the individual bytes, there's also no other ordering as there is with memory (due to memory's having of both addresses and values).

However, the choice of which is high and which is low doesn't change that together they hold the value 0x1234, as per our examples.

Comment: That seems to make sense, thank you for providing a clear explanation.

Comment: If you're ever in doubt, sometimes the easiest way is to test it yourself. Now, emulators are not always accurate, but if you don't have the real hardware, they're your best option.  For something like this you can trust nearly all emulators to get it right

Comment: @puppydrum64, this is a good comment, but more appropriate to direct to the OP rather than me.

Comment: Whoops, I commented on the wrong post!

Answer (score 0):

Is a manufacturer datasheet reliable source?
[Z80 user manual](https://www.zilog.com/docs/z80/um0080.pdf#page=113)
And of course in memory after opcode is firstly 0x34 then 0x12

Comment: I have that manual... it just says "Upon the execution of an LD HL, 5000h instruction, the HL register pair contains 5000h". Not terribly clear.

Comment: The question could have been answered by page 46 / 47 of the user manual which describes how ``ld de,0659h`` is encoded, unfortunately figure 37 was botched and shows ``and 7`` instead :-)